# Draw on canvas is way off in KitKat - works fine on older phones

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Im working on a function for my learn-to-code app where the users are supposed to be able to put markers on a map (a bitmap in a imageview). I have written something like this (C# in Xamarin):

```
   map.Touch += delegate(object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e) {

            if ((e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down ) && (e.Event.Action != MotionEventActions.Scroll ) )  {
                if ((downTime + 300) > e.Event.DownTime) {
                    x = e.Event.GetX();
                    y = e.Event.GetY();

                    mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.Copy (Bitmap.Config.Rgb565, true);
                    GC.Collect();
                    c = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
                    c.DrawBitmap (mutableBitmap, 0, 0, null);
                    c.Translate(0.07f, 0.07f);
                    c.DrawCircle(x, y, 30, paint);

                    map.SetImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);


                }
                else 
                    downTime = e.Event.DownTime;
            }
        };
```

On my older Nexus and on a Galaxy S3 this places the marker perfectly on the double tap and everything is well. Both devices are 4.3 or below. But! Then i got it tested on a Nexus 5 with Android 4.4.4. And now the marker is placed in the wrong place. The tester describes it like this:

"The offset changes depending where I tap, but it's not random. The offset is the same when I tap on the same place again.
Generally, the dot is drawn left of where I tap, and offset increases the further I tap right on the map.
Additionally, the dot is always closer to the horizontal middle then I want it to be, with the offset here also increasing if I tap further up/down on the image.

So no matter where I tap, I can never get the dot to show on the top/bottom 20%, and right... let's say about 40% of the image.
But this also means that the dot is complete accurate if I tap on the very left middle.
And the dot is also on the same location when I view the location on a saved item."

Okay, ive found some threads saying theres a drawing bugg in KitKat, and ive tried offseting it like this after suggestions in threads:

```
 c.Translate(0.07f, 0.07f);
```

Does not work. I have also tried putting my view (a dialog) to software layertype, like this:

```
   inputView.SetLayerType (Android.Views.LayerType.Software, null);
```

The problem persists. When loading the X and Y and image in a different view, the KitKat Nexus redraws the marker in the same place it put it - and not where it should be. I am having trouble finding good documentations for this, and im also quite the noob. So please, StackOverFlowers, help me!

Edit: My XML:

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollIt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:layout_width="1600px"
            android:layout_height="966px"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewMap"
            android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
    </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```